# Time zone datetime comparison in sql server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

In the database I have timezone and date as :

**Timezone**
'India Standard Time'

**DateTime**
'2018-07-19 15:47'

In Sql query I am comparing this with **GETUTCDATE()**

```
IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Notification] WHERE [Published] AT TIME ZONE  'India Standard Time'  <  GETUTCDATE())
  BEGIN
 PRINT 'True'
  END
```

This give me wrong result

I am new with this function so don't know exact way to compare it

Answer (score 1):

just use

> dateadd(MINUTE, 330, getutcdate())

in place of

> getutcdate()

for IST

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Notification] WHERE [Published]  <  dateadd(MINUTE, 330, getutcdate())
```

Comment: I am using sys.timezone which supports daylight saving

Comment: dateadd(MINUTE, 330, getutcdate() will provide the current indian date time

Comment: No , it is not fixed I have multiple time zone , sys.timezone

Comment: then how u bifurcate the dates by there time zones

Comment: User is selecting timezone and date time , on server side I have to compare with utcdatetime

Comment: CONVERT(datetime,SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset,GetUTCDate()),'+05:30')) use this with the timezone difference with UTC DATE

Comment: I know this, already using this , but it doesn't support daylight saying , that's why moving to use at time zone SQL server 2016

Comment: show us the result u r getting and desired result u want

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches to get this working -

My approach is to convert your GETUTCDATE to IST so that you can run your query without any timezone issues.

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Notification] 
WHERE [Published] < CONVERT(datetime,SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset,GETUTCDATE()),’+05:30′))
```

Comment: Or `GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE  'India Standard Time'`.

Comment: Please provide examples which compare time zone date time with UTC date time